# How to get editor type hints for a dataclass generated by make_dataclass function?

Tags: python, autocomplete, python-dataclasses

In my code i'm creating dataclass in runtime using [make_dataclass](https://docs.python.org/3/library/dataclasses.html#dataclasses.make_dataclass) and assign it to a variable

```py
from dataclasses import make_dataclassIn

Person = make_dataclass('Person', [('name', str), ('age', int)])
Person.__annotations__  # {'name': str, 'age': int}
```

in my editor (use lsp+pyrigh) when i do `Person.` it doesn't autocomplete

Need to know if  there  is anyway to make it autocomplete those classes that are created on the runtime ?